# Populate DropDownList from DataSource

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, datasource

I have an SQL Data Source which selects all rows of a table. I need to populate a dropdownlist with a certain field ('percentage') of all the rows, and when one is clicked to make the 'value' the rows 'id' field.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would want this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl_Items" runat="Server" DataTextField="percentage" 
     DataValueField="id" DataSourceId="sds_Items" />

<asp:SqlDataSource id="sds_Items" ...........other stuff........ />
```

You don't need to worry about assigning the value on click.  Just do it when you load the DropDownList in the first place.

Comment: Hello, how can I do that from Master Page where I need to bind the drop down in user controls with the same data from one place. Thanks